# Why does -Wcast-align not warn about cast from char* to int* on x86?

Tags: c, memory-alignment, gcc-warning, typecasting-operator

I understand that gcc has an option `-Wcast-align` which warns whenever a pointer is cast such that the required alignment of the target is increased.

Here's my program:

```
char data[10];
int ptr = *((int *)data);
```

On my machine, the alignment requirement of data is 1 whereas it's 8 for ptr.

Why don't I get a warning?

Could it be because I'm compiling it for x86?

Comment: The compiler probably aligns the array and detects it. Try it with a pointer parameter instead, or with `data+1`.

Comment: i think it is because you are casting an array pointer. i ran the code with data variable as just a char, it gave the warning perfectly

Comment: I changed it to 
 char *data = "aaaaa";
 int ptr = *((int *)data);
I still don't get any warning.
What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think the required alignment for pointers is 8 bytes on x86?

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - I'm missing the point

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update 2020-05-10:** As of GCC 8, the compiler supports the option `-Wcast-align=strict`, which will warn even on targets that are normally permissive of unaligned memory accesses. It is probably a good idea to have it enabled: [the compiler is free to optimise code with the assumption that the pointers are aligned, even on targets that would otherwise not care](https://trust-in-soft.com/blog/2020/04/06/gcc-always-assumes-aligned-pointer-accesses/).

---

The warning will never be emitted when compiling for Linux i386 or x86-64, when using the standard ABIs for these systems. Let me explain you why that is so.

First, let's see what [gcc's documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) has to say about `-Wcast-align` :

> Warn whenever a pointer is cast such that the required alignment of
> the target is increased. For example, warn if a `char *` is cast to an
> `int *` on machines where integers can only be accessed at two- or
> four-byte boundaries.

The Intel architecture does not require alignment of integers when using general-purpose instructions. Quoting from [Intel's Basic Architecture manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf), chapter 4.1.1 *Alignment of Words, Doublewords, Quadwords, and Double Quadwords* :

> Words, doublewords, and quadwords do not need to be aligned in memory
> on natural boundaries. The natural boundaries for words, double words,
> and quadwords are even-numbered addresses, addresses evenly divisible
> by four, and addresses evenly divisible by eight, respectively.
> However, to improve the performance of programs, data structures
> (especially stacks) should be aligned on natural boundaries whenever
> possible.

Alignment, therefore, is not strictly necessary, though highly recommended. There is, however, one exception to that rule, which you may have had in mind. Bit 18 of the `EFLAGS` register is known as the "Alignment Check" bit, and bit 18 of the `CR0` register is known as the "Alignment Mask" flag. When they are both set to 1, any memory accesses to data which is not aligned at its "natural boundary" (so, 2 bytes for words, 4 bytes for doublewords, and so on) results in `#AC`, the *Alignment Check Exception*. If you want to find out more about this, check out the [Intel System Programming Guide](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf).

However, neither the [System V ABI for i386](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf), nor the [System V ABI for x86-64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) specify that the Alignment Flag in EFLAGS is set. In fact, the i386 ABI notes the following on page 29, chapter 3-3 *Machine Interface* :

> The Intel386 architecture does not require all data access to be
> properly aligned. (...) Consequently, arbitrary data accesses, such as
> pointers dereference or reference arguments, might or might not be
> properly aligned. Accessing misaligned data will be slower than
> accessing properly aligned data, but otherwise there is no difference.

Although it also recommends that :

> Compilers should allocate independent data objects with the proper
> alignment.

GCC always knows the ABI of the platform for which it compiles code, and - in case of x86/64 - is aware of the fact that unaligned data access is allowed. This is why code like this will compile without a warning about alignment (let's forget about strict aliasing rules in the following examples) :

```
int main(void)
{
    char foo[] = "foobar";
    int bar = *(int*)(foo + 1);
    return 0;
}
```

If you try to compile this code with the gcc toolchain for ARM, you will get the warning :

```
daniel@Jurij:/tmp$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -Wcast-align align.c 
align.c: In function 'main':
align.c:4:13: warning: cast increases required alignment of target type [-Wcast-align]
  int bar = *(int*)(foo + 1);
```

This is because unaligned access is generally best avoided in ARM. I'm not an ARM expert, so I really can't say anything more than that.

Also, please note that most of what I wrote does not apply to SSE/AVX.

Comment: Right.  It works while I compile using gcc toolchain for ARM.

Comment: Followup: is it possible to force the warning to be displayed on x86/x86-64 _anyway_, (short of cross-compiling)?

Comment: @imallett : I haven't found anything like that in the GCC docs. I guess you're just better off posting an entirely new question.

Comment: @imallett Not on GCC, afaik. clang will display the warning on any platform, though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46790815/918959 C is not the machine architecture it runs on...